# Kendo UI Mobile & MySQL database connectivity

Tags: html, mysql, ios, cordova, kendo-ui

I am currently building a mobile application with Kendo UI which I intend to run through phonegap and deploy to some App Stores in the near future.

I have set out the layout in HTML, CSS & JS using the Kendo framework and everything is looking good and in place.

My app will talk to an existing MySQL database which already has lots of data in it. I am wanting to pull data out of the database and display it in my application. Can anybody with any experience with Kendo UI, phonegap and app deployment help me get started as the Kendo documentation for this is not very clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql database with lots of data is probably on a server somewhere.
Most servers that have mysql will probably have php installed.
So the easiest thing you can do is use some of the php mvc frameworks out there to get the data from the db, **convert that into json** and send that to your kendo-phonegap app.

You can read more about this approach [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/PHP/build-apps-with-kendo-ui-and-php).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use some wrappers. Kendo UI will not just take the data from your database.

For example setup the apache http server with php. The best way would be to get some lightweight framework which would handle the database for you. From client side with Kendo you will be querying your server.